# Why is my awk match not working?

Tags: regex, awk

I've got the following awk script:

```
/^[0-9]\{2\}$/ { print "found 2 digits"; }
```

I am running with the following command line into gawk:

```
gawk -f script.awk data.txt
```

The data file is

```
aa
32
gh
```

I am expecting one instance of "found 2 digits" to appear on stdout but I'm getting nothing.  Any ideas?  It appears to be related to the quantifier of {2} after some experimentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `--re-interval` option.

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/UIpfg)

Alternatively you can also specify `--posix` option.

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/y2QXJ)

Also you need to drop the `\` from in front of `{` and `}`.